# not show anything in use from the class in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, entity-framework

code does not display anything in `datagridview`
why?

```
class classman
        {
            public int id;
            public string name;
        }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testtelContext db = new testtelContext();
        List<classman> qry = (from p in db.firstlasts
                             join i in db.firstnames
                                 on p.Idfname equals i.Idfname
                              select new classman
                             {
                                 id = p.idfl,
                                 name = i.fname

                             }).ToList();
      BindingSource bs=new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = qry;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

    }
```

There is value in bindingsource but it does not display dataGridView5 show picture http://irphoto.ir/uploads/13658793021.jpg

Comment: Did my answer assist you with this question?

Comment: You should update your question instead of giving non-answers as answers to your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Probably need this:

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Right after you set the data source.